# I need declare a global array, but y my variable does not work, i have something like this:

Tags: c++

I tried with a #define but i don't know how use it in this context
the console print: 'array bound is not an integer constant', If you can help me I would appreciate it very much

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

//I get the value of my enviroment variable
char *vEviroment = getenv("Threads");
int number = atoi(vEnviroment)

//I need create an array with that value
long start[number];

int main(){

 //....
 
}
```

Comment: Hello close voters, the reason "needs debugging details" requires an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use run-time calls and data for global variable initialization. All global variables must be initialized with compile-time constants.

And (standard) C++ doesn't even have variable-length arrays, which means you can't create an array using variables whose values are set only at run-time.

The natural solution in C++ is to use a `std::vector` for `array`, then then early in the `main` function resize the vector using the correct size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

std::vector<long> start;

int main()
{
    // Get the environment variable, and check that it actually existed
    char* threads_env = std::getenv("Threads");
    if (threads_env == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get \"Threads\" environment variable\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Convert the string into an integer
    unsigned long threads = std::stoul(threads_env);

    // Resize the vector
    start.resize(threads);

    // Rest of the code
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of C++ language, You can't define Arrays without const integer type,

so in here:

```
long start[number];
```

You can't write "number" as a not constant type. You need to declare Array size with constant variable.

If you're looking for Dynamic Array, You can use `std::vector<>` (cppreferance:[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) )

Comment: That is not the immediate problem. And some C++ compilers (though not all) do support VLAs.

Comment: @Yunnosch Could u expand a bit with example Compilers? I know there is some tricks that define array with custom variables like using Initilazor list in classes. but for Global variable, I think there is no way

Comment: I won't. Because that is not the immediate problem here. And not the solution. In C++ vectors are the answer to variable lengths - as you have noted. The immediate problem I see is addressed in the answer by some programmer dude.